# "if yield" same as "yield if block evaluates to true"?

Tags: ruby

If I run the tests below on this code, it returns

```
 ALERT: an event that always happens
```

I expected it to also put

```
 ALERT: an event that never happens
```

but it didn't. I assume the reason for the difference is the 'true' and 'false' in the respective tests, but I don't see why 'true' or 'false' make a difference in this case. The method 'event' says

```
puts "ALERT: #{name}" if yield
```

If the result of the tests is explained by the fact that 'true' equals 'yield' in this context, whereas 'false' doesn't, how does 'false' negate 'yield'?

Question: Does 'if yield' mean 'yield if the block evaluates to true'?

**code**

```
def event(name)
  puts "ALERT: #{name}" if yield
end

Dir.glob('*events.rb').each {|file| load file }
```

**tests**

```
event "an event that always happens" do
  true                     
end

event "an event that never happens" do
  false                       
end
```

**Output**

```
ALERT: an event that always happens
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be helpful.

```
def event(name)
  val = yield
  puts val.inspect
  puts "ALERT: #{name}" if val == "donald"
end

event "an event that always happens" do
  "donald"
end

event "an event that never happens" do
  "duck"
end
```

prints

```
"donald"
ALERT: an event that always happens
"duck"
```

Basically the return value of yield is whatever gets evaluated last in the block. And that is what is being used as a criteria in the if statement.

Comment: Remember also that only `nil` and `false` are going to evaluate as false. Everything else, including 0, an empty string, an empty array, or an empty hash, will evaluate as true.

Answer (score 2):

> Question: Does 'if yield' mean 'yield if the block evaluates to true'?

No, `if yield` means if ((result of executing the block)), that is to say that the block is always evaluated, and its result is used as the condition of the if statement.

`puts "..." if yield` means "puts only if true". It is equivalent to

```
if yield
then
    puts "ALERT: #{name}"
```

That's why you see only one output. With the second event invocation, puts is not executed at all because of `if false`. Try this :

```
def event(name)
    result = yield
    puts "the block is #{result}"
    puts "ALERT: #{name}" if result
end

$ ruby -w t.rb 
the block is true
ALERT: an event that always happens
the block is false
$
```